# Regex Help - what can do to make it generic

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence

> When the Forward Sensing Camera (FSC) detects a vehicle ahead or pedestrian and determines
> that a collision with the object is unavoidable while the vehicle is driven at a vehicle
> speed of about 4 to 80 km/h (2 to 50 mph) if the object is a vehicle ahead and 2 to  50km/hr if the object is pedestrian

My goal is to get all the speed ranges. Currently, I am using the regex

```
\d+ to \d+\s?(km\/hr|km\/h| mph)
```

The only issue is that I have hard-coded a to in the regex. The speed could also be specified as 5 - 25 kmph.

I am lost as to what a generic character sequence could be to cater to anything between two numbers

Comment: If only `to` or `-` is possible, then use `\d+ (?:to|-) \d+\s?(km\/hr|km\/h| mph)`. If you expect anything other than word chars, ``\d+\W+\d+\s?(km\/hr|km\/h| mph)``

Comment: shouldn't you know the options of the input?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  " Yes . That is the strategy I am opting for now" Thanks  . My modified Regex is /\d+\s?(to|-)\s?\d+\s?(km\/hr|km\/h| mph|kmph)/gm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `k` optional and use an alternation:

```
\b\d+ (?:-|to) \d+\s?(?:km\/hr?| k?mph)\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+`  Match 1+ digits and
- `(?:-|to)` Match either `-` or `to`
- `\d+\s?` Match 1+ digits with an optional whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `km\/hr?| k?mph` Match either `km/h` `km/hr`  `mph`  `kmph`
- `)` Close the group
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IVQRQV/1)

Note that there is also a space in  `k?mph` which you match 2 spaces as there is also `\s?`

If you don't want 2 spaces, you could write it as:

```
\b\d+ (?:-|to) \d+(?: ?km\/hr?| k?mph)\b
```